# How to test python script within PHP

Tags: php, python

I am working on a .php file that takes a python function as an input. Then it checks the function if it returns the correct output.

First, I created a form in func.php. In the form, there is a textarea to input the function.

```
 <textarea id="function" name="function" rows="10" cols="70" placeholder="Enter your function here..." required></textarea>
```

So the user types his/her function(python) and then makes clic on summit button. Next the function is store into a variable.

```
$func =$_POST['function'];
```

After the python function was saved, I want to test the function and see what it outputs. Assume I already have some parameters to test it.

I read some articles and they said that I can use exec() to execute a python script, but according to those examples it executes a .py file. In my case, I don't have a .py file but only the python function. I was thinking on creating a .py file within PHP using fopen and save my function there.

Python Code(*)

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys

#printme function was the function that was input in the textarea
def printme( str ):
   print str
   return
if(__name__=='__main__'):
   printme(sys.argv[0])
```

Then execute the .py file using exec()

```
 exec("python myfile.py Monday",$output);
```

But I don't know if fopen can open a .py file. I also tried to store the python code(*) in an string variable named $code and run it.

```
 exec("python $code Monday",$output);
```

But it didn't work.
Please can someone help with this? Thank you in advance

Comment: you can run python at the command line: `python -c code_goes_here`. but note that you ARE passing user input DIRECTLY to your command line, means you're vulnerable to command-line injection attacks, and you are basically opening up your system to a COMPLETE remote compromise.

Comment: You can create a *.py file witih fopen. Your problem will be concurrent access. If I submit the form at the same time that you submit it, we will both try to create the python file at the same time. You will need to implement file locking.

Comment: What you're looking to do is a huge security risk. One solution is to whitelist functions to call. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/php/2781/security/14399/command-line-injection#t=201607271330264355227